# Connecting to Strophe.js in Angular 6

Tags: xmpp, angular6, chat, strophe.js

I have connected to Strophe.js by placing the Strophe.js files in assets and Connection is successful. But after connecting to it, UI is getting hanged. Can any one please help

Answer (score 1):

what means hanged? Strophe.js does't block the process.
i remeber connect like this(not exact code):

```
var callback = function(condition){
    // according to condition decide if connected or not
    // and if connected, UI: form login panel to main panel(include friends list and so on) 

}
Strophe.connection(jid, password, callback);
```

and there is no reason UI hanged. you may use broswer debug tool to follow your code and find out where it hanged